# ProgressBar like Battery Charging

Tags: android-progressbar

I need a idea to develop the `ProgressBar` like `Battery Indicator` Symbol. that means need to overwrite the Spinner Icon.

While my process is Progressing i need to show the `ProgressBar` like Battery Changing and increase the Progress percentage until it is done. (100%).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got 11 levels of battery charge `ICONS` from [here](http://mrluksy.deviantart.com/art/Battery-ico-for-RocketDock-90069597). and i update the image depends upon the progress level.

So it came like progress update.

Thanks to [DEVIAN-ART](http://mrluksy.deviantart.com/art/Battery-ico-for-RocketDock-90069597)

Answer (score 0):

Battery indicators could be found on http://www.flaticon.com/search?word=battery and calculated as a simple progress bar.

Use a conditional statement to show a battery status icon related to the pourcentage of works done.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

 private ProgressBar mProgress;
 private int mProgressStatus = 0;

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

     mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 mProgressStatus = doWork();

                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }).start();
 }
 }
```

Do any heavy cpu work in the *doWork* method and set the appropriate icon.

Comment: i need  to design progressBar like Battery icon. and then show the increment value as well as increase that battery icon level